# The dilemma of a high-paid junior

Tags: career-development, career-switch, careers

I have 2 years of experience and 1.5 years of research experience. I currently have a dilemma that the job I'm in now is paying me above industry standard (but within the company, my skills are still underpaid). I am not learning anything technical in my role, and my expertise is not growing that much. I'm already the expert in the field in my team. I enjoy the flexibility given to me by my company too.

But I need I need to grow, which is something this company can't provide for me, and even their dedication in my field is questionable in the long run, to the point that I'm constantly worried about my future in this company.

If I switch to another company, the difference in my salary will be minor compared to what I've got today, but with less flexibility and more demanding work.

Basically I will work a lot more just to have a small increase in my compensation. If I project what I'm expecting to be paid with another company during an interview, they think I am asking for too much despite it's just a reasonable increase when compared to my current package. They would just think it's already too much for them considering my experience.

So, what should I do in this case to get the most I can out of the situation? To stay, or not to stay? In either case, what should be the proper strategies?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with the site

Comment: That being said, your whole second paragraph assumes a lot of things that are not necessarily true, and perhaps that is creating noise to you... you mention you want and need to learn and grow, and your current company isn't providing your that. Seems to me that what you need is obvious and you already know what you should do, don't you think?

Comment: I've zero idea of why this legitimate question is voted down. It's discouraging and doesn't help with the conversation at all.

Comment: @HingWong, First, stop thinking of yourself a junior developer, start thinking of yourself as a senior developer. "they think I am asking for too much despite it's just a reasonable increase when compared to my current package." And that's fine, they can always say no to you. If a potential employer says no to you when you're still currently employed, it's really not the end of the world. Just keep on applying to other jobs. And stop second-guessing what potential employers are going to think. Just apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question boarders on 'opinion', a section that isn't usually allowed, but since you've indicated you are in a junior position, I think there are some elements I can help with.

In terms of your current position, if they are paying you above market rates and offering flexibility, this is something that is generally highly desirable in corporate life. It means the company is invested in you and wants to retain you - this is a good thing.

If you aren't being challenged at work currently, there is absolutely nothing to stop you from talking with your Management and saying:

"Boss, I love the team here, I love the Flexibility - but I'm looking for more challenge - I think that if we were to look at XYZ, it could really help deliver growth/increased profits/decreased costs/other business reason for the company, and I'd like to investigate the possibility of XYZ to advance my career"

Find something you are passionate about, something that is in your field of expertise, write a business case on how deploying it to the business could yield a benefit to the business and then go with it.

In terms of your other options - you say you aren't being challenged in your current role, but if you move companies you expect a slight increase in compensation, but with more demanding work.

I'm not sure if there is something that got lost in translation - but those are mutually exclusive - Either you want more Challenging work or you don't.

In terms of Salary projection, in our idealized world, we would see a gradually and consistent trend upwards with our Salary, regular increases etc. And whilst this is something to aim for, it's not always the case. Sometimes you stagnate, sometimes there is an opportunity where the long-term, non-financial benefits would mitigate a short-term salary decrease - don't be so proud that you turn your nose up at a job that would be beneficial for you development and career wise, just because the salary is a little less than you want.

Ultimately, you have to decide what you value more - Money and easy work or pushing yourself to be a better you.

My 2c (which is the whole reason I er'd on the side of this not being an opinion question) is to say that as above there is nothing to stop you from trying to create work/projects in your current position that will provide you with the growth and challenge that you crave.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what should I do in this case to get the most I can out of the
> situation? To stay, or not to stay? In either case, what should be the
> proper strategies?

You should decide what is important to you, and pursue the path that gets you there.

- is not working hard most important to you?
- is salary most important to you?
- is long term career growth most important to you?
- is flexibility most important to you?

It's your life and your career. You get to decide where it goes.